# Tracks uploaded via java or python code are not showing up on soundcloud profile

Tags: java, python, soundcloud

We are developing a program that will include a function for uploading wav-files to SoundCloud. We have tried to code this in both java and python, but we are having problems with the tracks not showing up on our [profile](https://soundcloud.com/RubberBeats) or in the stream of our followers. The tracks are only showing on the [track page](https://soundcloud.com/rubberbeats/tracks).

After upploading a track via java or python: If I log on as RubberBeats (in a web browser), the uploaded track shows the message "This track is being processed" and I am not able to play it.
When I am logged on as an other user I can not see the uploaded track on RubberBeats' profile page, but it is available on the track page. If I play the track once from this page, it suddenly shows up on RubberBeats's profile page. Logged in as RubberBeats, the track no longer shows the message "This track is being processed" and is now playable from this profile as well.

**See image at :** [First Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPFqF.png) **or** [Second Option](https://d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1193627/RackMultipart20150424-12819-1qxoey1-Skjermbilde_2015-04-24_kl._17.32.00.png?1429889727)

This is how it looks from the RubberBeats profile (we changed the name from Loopify to RubberBeats). "Test upload with java 4" has been stuck on processing for 55 mins (and it's a 2 sec. track!). "Test upload with java 3" havs been played two times by other users, after this it became playable from the RubberBeats profile.

Java code:

```
import de.voidplus.soundcloud.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

SoundCloud soundcloud;

void setup()
{
soundcloud = new SoundCloud("CLIENT ID", "CLIENT SECRET");

soundcloud.login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

Track track = soundcloud.postTrack(new Track("Test upload with java 4", "/Users/emweyd/Documents/lydspor.wav"));

println(track.getTitle()+" (#"+track.getId()+")");
}

void draw()
{
}
```

**NOTE:** We are using nok's soundcloud [library](https://github.com/nok/soundcloud-java-library) for java . SoundCloud dropped the support for the official SoundCloud [Java API wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper), which is a primary dependency. It still seems to work pretty well though.

Python code:

```
import soundcloud

# create client object with app and user credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='CLIENT ID',
                       client_secret='CLIENT SECRET',
                       username='USERNAME',
                       password='PASSWORD')

# print authenticated user's username
print client.get('/me').username

# upload audio file
track = client.post('/tracks', track={
'title': 'This is my sound','tag_list': 'RubberTracks',
'asset_data': open('C:\Users\Anja-PC\Desktop\Testopptak.mp3', 'rb')
})

# print track link
print track.permalink_url
```

Tracks not showing up is a big problem for us because we want the music to be easily found by other users. Is it possible to fix this problem and make the tracks show up on our profile immediately after upload?